# Linux shell (Bash/Z shell) - change background color when under a specific directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, console, zsh

I would like to change the background color of a shell (Z shell, but Bash will do as well) every time I go under a specific directory. For example, I would like to change the background color every time I am in */mnt/data* to say red and change it back to normal if I go out of /mnt/data/...

To change the background and preserve my current prompt, I do:

```
export PS1="$PS1 %{$'\e[0;41m'%}"
```

I am not sure how to hook this up so that it is evaluated (wrapped in an *if* statement) every time I change working directory.

Comment: So you want to change to background after the prompt?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trick is to use the command substitution in PS1. The following kind of works for me in Bash:

```
PS1='$(if [[ $PWD == /mnt/data* ]] ; then printf "\[\e[0;41m\]" ; else printf "\[\e[m\]" ; fi) %'
```

By "kind of" I mean the fact that the behaviour on the command line immediately after changing to/from the directory is a bit weird (e.g., the background changes after you press <kbd>Backspace</kbd>).

You can also use the [PROMPT_COMMAND](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) shell variable which is more suitable for code than the prompt itself:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='if [[ $PWD == /mnt/data* ]] ; then printf "\e[0;41m" ; else printf "\e[m" ; fi'
```

It's cleaner to keep the code in a function with all the proper indentation, and just call the function from the variable:

```
colour_mnt_data () {
    if [[ $PWD == /mnt/data* ]] ; then
        printf '\e[0;41m'
    else
        printf '\e[m'
    fi
}
PROMPT_COMMAND='colour_mnt_data'
```

Comment: You can keep the indentation inside the RHS of the assignment of PROMPT_COMMAND as well.  Newlines and indentation have no effect inside single quotes.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: True. But for a function, syntax highlighting in your editor works, you can test the function outside of the prompt, etc.

Answer (score 7):

### Answer for `zsh` (although the second part can be adapted to `bash`):

This is a two-part problem:

1. **Acting on directory changes:** For `zsh` you can just use the `chpwd` hook function. `chpwd` as well as any function listed in the `chpwd_functions` array are called each time the current working directory is changed.

   So, if you want to react to certain directories you can use something like this

   ```sh
   # load helper function to manipulate hook arrays
   autoload -Uz add-zsh-hook

   # define hook function, decide on action based on $PWD, the new pwd.
   chback_on_chdir () {
       case $PWD in
           /mnt/data/* )
               # change background, when entering subdirectories of "/mnt/data"
               ;;
           /home )
               # change background, when entering exactly "/home"
               ;;
           /usr | /usr/* ) 
               # change background, when entering "/usr" or a subdirectory thereof
               ;;
           * )
               # change background, when entering any other directory
               ;;
       esac
   }

   # add chback_on_chdir to chpwd_functions
   add-zsh-hook chpwd chback_on_chdir
   ```
2. **Changing the background color:** There are actually two ways to change the background color.

   - You can change the background for the following printed characters within the colors available within the terminal (which is, what you do in your example). In `zsh` this could be done like this (shortened example for `chdir` hook):

     ```sh
     # allow for parameter substitution in prompts
     setopt PROMPT_SUBST
     # add string `$COLOR` to $PS1. 
     # Note the `\` before `${COLOR}`, which prevents immediate evaluation.
     # `${COLOR}` will be substituted each time the prompt is printed
     PS1="$PS1\${COLOR}"

     chpwd () {
         case $PWD in
             /mnt/data/* )
                 # set background color to red
                 COLOR='%K{red}'
                 ;;
             * )
                 # reset background color to default
                 COLOR='%k'
                 # could also be just an empty string
                 #COLOR=''
                 # or unset
                 #unset COLOR
                 ;;
         esac
     }
     ```
   - In some (many?) terminals you can also redefine the default background color. This will actually change the background color everywhere, even on already printed text and "unprinted" locations. This can be done by utilizing [XTerm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html), which - despite their name - work in other terminal emulatores, too. (I tested successfully with `xterm`, `urxvt`, `gnome-terminal` and `termite`). The control sequence in question is

     ```sh
     ESC]11;<color>ST
     ```

     where `ESC` is the escape character `\e`, `<color>` is a color specification (e.g. `red`, `#ff0000`, `rgb:ff/00/00`, `rgbi:1/0/0` - what actually works might depend on the terminal) and `ST` is the *string terminator* `\e\\` (`ESC\`). You can send it to the terminal with

     ```sh
     printf "\e]11;red\e\\"
     ```

     You can reset the color to the configured default with the control sequence

     ```sh
     ESC]111ST
     ```

     using the command

     ```sh
     printf "\e]111\e\\"
     ```

     So, if you usually have a black background and want to tint it slightly red when entering `/mnt/data` or a directory below it, you can use:

     ```sh
     chpwd () {
         case $PWD in
             /mnt/data | /mnt/data/* )
                 # set background color to a dark red
                 printf "\e]11;#1f0000\e\\"
                 ;;
             * )
                 # reset the background color to configured default
                 printf "\e]111\e\\"
                 ;;
         esac
     }
     ```

     **Note:** I found that it does not seem to work on `urxvt`, if transparency is enabled.

     It is possible to retrieve the current value by replacing the color specification with `?`:

     ```sh
     printf "\e]11;?\e\\" ; sleep 1
     ```

     The `sleep 1` is needed so that the output is not immediately overwritten by the prompt.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to write a script file with functions that you can call to determine what your PS1 should be because of the directory that you are in.

Then, you source this script file in your .bashrc and set your PS1 so that it calls the function from your script file to set its value.

```
  . ~/.myCleverPS1

  export PS1='$PS1 $(myCleverPS1func " (%s)") $ '
```

An example you can look at is the git-completion script which adds the name of the current branch to the prompt whenever you are in a git repo directory (and can optionally colorize too).

See as example: https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/contrib/completion